# System of linear equations with matrix power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, $z_1,\dots,z_{n+1}\in\mathbb{R}^d$, satisfying the following system of linear equations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
A^nz_{n+1}=0,\\
A^{n-1}z_{n+1}+A^nz_{n}=0,\\
\dots \dots\\
z_{n+1}+Az_{n}+\dots+A^nz_1=0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
I would like to conclude that each term in the summands is $0$. I know that if $A$ is symmetric, then $\mathrm{ker}(A)=\mathrm{ker}(A^i)$, $\forall i\ge 1$, then the above equation implies that all terms are $0$. This is not true in general, if we take $n=1$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $z_2=[1, 0]$, $z_1=[-1, 0]$. What conditions do I need to impose on $A$?

Comment: Since nontrivial Jordan blocks are a problem, you can restrict yourself to nonsingular diagonalizable matrices then the problem reduces to diagonal matrices.